# Shared Preferences doesn't seem to save username in session

Tags: android, authentication, logout, sharedpreferences

For a few days, I have been trying to get the username to save in session properly. First, I opened the app and it would open login screen. I login with username, then it would take me to the MainActivity. Now I exit the app and reopen the app to ensure that username is saved and it would pass the login screen and go straight to the MainActivity. So far so good, then I would logout and it would go back to the login screen. I want to make sure that it is completely logged out so i exit the app and reopen the app and it would take me to the MainActivity. I couldn't figure out how to fix that problem.

my login class

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("username", username);
        editor.commit();


        if(prefs.getString("username", null)!=username)
        {Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Customer.class); 
        startActivity(i);}


        etUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        btnCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
        lblResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            //@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // Check Login
            String username = etUsername.getText().toString();

            if(username.equals("1111")){
                lblResult.setText("Login successful.");

                 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
```

my logout class

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.logout);

        code = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.codeout);
        btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        lblResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String logout = code.getText().toString();

                if (logout.equals("99")){
                    lblResult.setText("Logout successful");

                    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.remove("username");
                    editor.commit();

                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    finish();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, it looks like you are setting `username` in your preferences and then immediately checking that value. It appears that this `if` statement would always pass:

```
if(prefs.getString("username", null)!=username)
```

Also, as @inazaruk pointed out, you should use `equals()` instead of `==` for a `String` comparison.

Comment: @Tanner I will remember that now for String comparison. Im not sure which == I have within my coding but i also edited the line as mentioned below it would never open the login screen even after logout.

Comment: @merrill So is the code you posted in your question accurate with the code you are having issues with? If not, why don't you edit your original post with the most recent code you have.

Comment: @Tanner the only changes I made is `if(prefs.getString("username", null)!=username)`
and if i do `if(!prefs.getString("username", "").equals(username))` it would never see the login screen at all

Comment: even if i logout and if i use this `if(!prefs.getString("username", null).equals(username))` it gives an error when attempting to open the app

Comment: @Tanner error that force close the app, since you were focusing on that last line asking "what error?" does that mean that line is the best one out of the three mentioned?. Also besides the error, the other line i mentioned before that only goes to mainActivity and never see the login screen at all. I couldn't seem to find the right code to fix that line and work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You should compare the strings using the `equals()` method, not `!=`. Also, don't give null as default:

```
if(!prefs.getString("username", "").equals(username))
```

Comment: @MByD thanks for the tip for the equals(). Now that I edited it, it is not going to the login screen at all (both times when logout or when open app it would go to the MainActivity)

Comment: @MByD is there a another way that would respond to default besides null and ""?

Comment: @merrill - I'm sorry but I don't understand your question, could you explain more?

Comment: @MByD since you said don't give null as default what can be replaced for null? you replaced it with "" but with that line it would never open login screen at all. How can I compare in string using equals() with not equal 'as in !=' without putting ! before the prefs another words what code can be same as != for string comparison?

Comment: You need the `!` and `equals` as I used. determine a value that cannot be a username (such as "") and compare to it, or call `contains` to see if a username exists in the sharedpreferences.

Comment: can i put !.equals() together? what are some example to put for ""?